# Modify database table best practices

Tags: mysql, database-design

As my title states, I'm curious about the best practices for modifying an existing table in a (mysql) database. In my scenario, I have a table that is already full of data and has a column named `product_id` that is currently the primary key for the table. I'm working on a feature where I'm finding `product_id` doesn't necessarily need to be unique or the primary key, since I want to allow multiple records for the same product. Database design isn't a strength of mine yet, but in my head I feel like what I would want to do is run the command DROP PRIMARY KEY for the `product_id` column, then add a column called `id` and making this the new primary key. Then I would need to update the `id` column for each record with a unique id for it to be a valid primary key. As far as database design is concerned, is this the best practice for doing this or is it better to create a new table with the updated structure and copying the current records into the new table?

EDIT:
More about the feature I'm working on. The products are books and I'm trying to allow multiple sections of these books to be previewed. In order to do this, I'm storing page ranges that can be previewed. Right now, only one page range is allowed, which is why the product id doesn't need to be unique anymore.

Comment: Whatever, do a backup before you try anything

Comment: Not sure how one product can be more than one product. Maybe if you explain what you actually mean by that we could suggest a good solution

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated the question to explain more about the feature I'm working on.

Comment: Create new table with `product_id` as a foreign key. Put any number rows indicating  page ranges in the new tables with the same `product_id` to denote multiple ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primary key is ALWAYS unique.

Why do you don't want it to be unique? It sounds like you are exposing the key outside the database, that the PK is visible somehow and some user(s) think it should behave differently. If this is the case then this is a really bad practice.

This is the typical case of the notorious "natural keys". They are a disaster waiting to happen; I don't like big time bombs. I've been strongly opposed to them for some time now. It's good they teach them in schools so you know what **not to use in the real world**.

Now for the solution. If `product_id` is exposed, then it shouldn't be the PK at all. Solution?

- Create a new column (`id` maybe?) that is internal, that is unique, and not exposed to the user, while keeping `product_id`. This new column could have the exact same value as `product_id` at first.
- Change all FK references from other tables to the new `id` column.
- Then, remove the PK constraint from `product_id` and do whatever you want to do with it.
- Add the PK contraint to the new `id` column.

Comment: Hi thanks for this! The schema I'm working with is kind of odd since it's code I inherited from a previous programmer. I had some unique challenges that I lack experience with and these suggestions were very helpful to work through it.